# Proving an inequality using moment inequalities

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable such that probability, $P(a\leq X\leq b) = 1$ where $-\infty <a <b <+\infty$. Show that var$(X)\leq (b-a)^2/4$ using moment inequalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that $X$ is a continuous random variable having a probability
density function $f:[a,b]\to [0,+\infty)$. Let $\mu=\int_{a}^bxf(x)dx\in [a,b]$ and consider the integral
$$0\leq\int_{a}^b(b-x)(x-a)f(x)dx=\int_{a}^b((b-\mu)-(x-\mu))\cdot((x-\mu)+(\mu-a))f(x)dx\\
=(b-\mu)(\mu-a)-\int_{a}^b(x-\mu)^2f(x)dx.$$
Hence
$$\mbox{Var}(X)=\int_{a}^b(x-\mu)^2f(x)dx\leq (b-\mu)(\mu-a)\leq \frac{(b-a)^2}{4}.$$

Comment: The random variable $X$ does not necessarily have a density, right?

Comment: You assume that the distribution of $X$ is absolutely continuous, i.e. it has a density function. But there is no such an assumption in the question.